# Getting notifications about controls creations in WPF

Tags: wpf, controls

Is there a way in WPF that I can get notified whenever a WPF control is created or destroyed?
(For example an event I can register to "Control.ControlCreated"...)

Answer (score 0):

What about [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) and [Initialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.initialized.aspx) events of `FrameworkElement` class (and their counterparts)?
They are not routed events but with some styling and `EventSetters` they can be hooked to all required controls. The rest depends on what you need to do in event handler.

Other than that, I don`t see any common [control events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control_events.aspx) that can satisfy your requirements.